# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not being called

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5

Hi i am now problem with orientation of viewcontroller. the following is my .h file.

```
@interface IPad_HomeViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
    UIAlertView *alertWithYesNoButtons;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStatus;

@end
```

i implement the following method in .m file.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return NO;
}
```

then i made a breakpoint. i realized shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is totally not being called. don't know why it is not being called.

pls advise me.
thanks

Comment: what method you used to show that view means addSubview or PresentModalViewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is because your UINavigationController handles the call. Implement the following to send it back to the viewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

// pre-iOS 6 support
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roland, i saw error in supportedInterfaceOrientations. 'Property 'viewControllers' not found on object of type 'IPad_HomeViewController*'

Comment: Then 'IPad_HomeViewController' is not a UINavigationController or a subclass from it.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation support changed a lot between iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Go to your project's target summary page and check "iPhone/Ipod Deployment Info" and there "Supported Interface Orientations". Have you enabled device rotation?